# Cannot see wireless adapter in my windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, sony-vaio

I am stuck here for 4 days now. I was cleaning my PC where I uninstalled some of the software I thought were never used. I even stopped some of the default start applications during the booting of windows 7.

I was connected to WiFi and everything worked fine until I restarted. After I restarted I did not see the option for wireless. I could see nothing and have been connected to the LAN cable. Please help me here. Since then, I have installed all kinds of drivers, updated BIOS, but nothing helped. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

I checked that the network settings does not list my wireless adapter although it does list the Bluetooth adapter.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked under Device manager?

Comment: "I was cleaning my PC where I uninstalled some of the software I thought were never used."   Do a Windows 7 Repair Install to see if you can fix this issue. See this tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html  . Maybe now is the time to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yeah, it is not there

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Have added the screenshot

Comment: Install the drivers for the network controller with the question mark.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I tried but it says could not find

Comment: There seems to have wireless drivers for you PC here: https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/sony/laptops-desktops/vpceh25en/21880 Give it a try if you have not done it yet.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I had tried `netsh wlan show profiles` but it gives there is no wireless interface on the system`

Comment: Right click on the network icon on the taskbar, then "Troubleshoot problems". Maybe Windows will give you a hint of the problem